# Help me find a film with a pegasus, an astronaut and Chosen Children

Tags: story-identification, movie

Stay with me, because my memory of this is going to come in patches.
I have this memory of a film I saw at least 10 years ago, and I think the main plot was about these children chosen because they're special (I don't know)
Other small details that come through:
- They flew a pegasus somewhere 
- The boy protagonist's hero was some female astronaut
- There was a scene where there was all this great food but it was like, sand?
I have no idea what the title would be, what actors might be in it.
If someone could help me out with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What ages were the kids, did the food turn into sand or was it sand to begin with (disguised as food)?

Comment: youngest kid was probably... 10-12? oldest maybe 14-16? Sand disguised as food. (it sounds like you may know what I'm talking about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it is from the mini-series based the Time Quartet trilogy by Madeleine L'Engle, the third book in the Time Quartet ("A Wrinkle in Time", "Wind in the Door", "A Swiftly Tilting Planet" (movie was ~2003).

I don't remember the specific scene in the mini-series, however, in one part of the books on of the protagonists in Chapter 7 of the first book:

> "The Man with the Red Eyes serves the children an elaborate turkey dinner, but to Charles all the food tastes like sand. The man explains that the food is synthetic, but Charles would be able to taste it if only he would open his mind to IT. He invites Charles to come with him and learn who he really is, and Charles agrees in spite of Meg's strong protestations. The man stares into Charles Wallace's eyes until the boy's pupils fade into the surrounding blue irises. Once extricated from the man's hypnotic stare, Charles acts like a different person. He asks Meg why she is being so "belligerent and uncooperative" and bids her eat the food prepared for them, which he now claims is delicious. Horrified, Meg shrieks to Calvin that the boy beside them is no longer Charles; the Charles they know is gone."

[Wiki Link - A Swiftly Tilting Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Swiftly_Tilting_Planet)

[Wiki Link - A Wrinkle in Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time)

[IMDB Time Quartet MiniSeries](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290382/)

[Wiki - A Wrinkle In Time Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time_%28film%29)

Comment: YOU ARE INCREDIBLE THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS IS IT.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Glad I could be of assistance.  If this is indeed the answer you were seeking, then next steps are to have you select the answer as correct to let others know the question has been answered.  Thanks.